# Segmentation Fault in C causing code to run sometimes but not other times

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am making a short program that gives me the initials of a name, so if the name was john smith, it would give me JS.

The code I wrote is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    string name = "String Name Goes here"

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(name); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(name[i]));
        while(name[i] != ' ')
        {
            i++;
        } 
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So since I just used a generic string name, the results I should get are SNGH. The problem is, the code is working sometimes, and other times I get the segmentation error. It always comes up when there are capital letters in the string, but when there are no capital letters in the string, sometimes it outputs what I want. I understand that this has something to do with accessing memory I am not allowed to, but I don't see how that applies here, because I am only accessing the i counter.

Any reason why this is happening?

*EDIT: The reason I am using 'string' is because I am accessing a different library that I did not list here that defines a function to get a string. So I could get the string alright, I just substituted the code for what I had before. That's not the part thats causing the problem.

Comment: why not using char *str = malloc(sizeof(buffer_length));

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I actually don't know what a string is in his code. It could be a `typedef`, it could be `std::string` (and the OP using C++), it could even be a macro or something else entirely. It was not sarcastic, I genuinely wanted to know what `string` is.

Comment: @cnicutar Alright then. I'm sorry for misunderstanding it.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: how could he know what string is, when even the compiler does not know it! RE(update) **what is string?**

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I found the way cnicutar answer much more interesting that giving directly the answer since pointing out to the problem is sometimes better as directly giving the solution...

Comment: Will it Ever compile ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, if the string you are processing does not end with a space character, this loops will skip over the string terminator and looks for a space character in the memory beyond the `name` variable. If it finds a space character before it reaches too far the program terminates successfully. If it does not find a space eventually you get a "segmentation fault" error for trying to read from an invalid memory location.

```
    while(name[i] != ' ')
    {
        i++;
    }
```

The fix is checking for the string terminator character in addition to spaces:

```
    while(name[i] != ' ' && name[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
```

<sub>This is, of course, assuming that `string` here is actually a C string: `char[]` or `char*`</sub>

You could find this out yourself for example by running the program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/). The output you would get tells you that the `while`-statement on line 12 uses uninitialized memory:

```
==9110== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9110==    at 0x4006B1: main (test.c:12)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the fix. The problem wasn't with the string, but with the && condition. I am still new in C, and didn't know about the null condition.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are using what look like C++ headers. You only need `<stdio.h>` for your program.

There is no established type `string` in C (even though you can define one). Strings can be stored in such things as `char` arrays, so your variable declaration should look like this:

```
char* name = "String Name Goes here";
```

If you *do* have a `string` type that's defined in another library, the only proper way to get its length and other properties is by using the functions *that library provides*. You cannot have a custom string type and assume it's null terminated (that's what `strlen` and others assume).

But *if it is* (assuming a C-like `char[]`, that is), the following

```
while(name[i] != ' ')
{
    i++;
}
```

*will always* go out of bounds, unless the source text does ends with a space. It might eventually stop at a garbage whitespace (if you're unlucky) or cause a segmentation fault (if you're lucky). In any case, it *does* attempt to access memory it's not supposed to (as you correctly guessed in your question) and it invokes what we call *undefined behavior*.